# wpf TreeView - How to call function on IsExpanded property change

Tags: wpf, treeview

Is there a way in XAML to call a function when the TreeViewItem property IsExpanded changes?

I believe the not so good alternative would be to loop through all TreeViewItems and do an item.IsExpanded += handler call if I understand things correctly.

Or I could check for clicks on the expander element I guess.

What I'm doing is persisting the expand/collapse state of the tree. Please answer the first question before suggesting alternative ways to persist this just to edify me on properties and xaml.

Answer (score 1):

I would bind the IsExpanded property of the TreeViewItem to my model using something like:

```
                    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
                        </Style>
                    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then I can run thru the model and get the value for IsExpanded and save it. Additionally, when restoring, simply set the IsExpanded property.

Since you need to call other code when changed, implement IsExpanded like so:

```
private bool _IsExpanded;
public bool IsExpanded
{
    get { return _IsExpanded; }
    set
    {
        if (_IsExpanded == value) return;
        _IsExpanded = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged( "IsExpanded" );//or however you need to do it
        CallSomeOtherFunc();//this is the code that you need to be called when changed.
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work for me as I need to execute code when the change occurs. However yeah this is the good solution.

Comment: Then just put code in the ViewModel for the set of IsExpanded. public bool IsExpanded { get { return _IsExpanded; } set { _IsExpanded = value; CallSomeOtherFunc(); } } Of course I've omitted the code for INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it. No need for code behind. If you use something like caliburn.micro, everything would be much easier.

Comment: Even easier if you use Fody's PropertyChanged nuget package which allows for simple INotifyPropertyChanged along with being able to write OnPropertyChanged functions that automatically get called when the property changes. https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/On_PropertyName_Changed

Answer (score 1):

Building on Joel's answer, you can use `EventSetter`s in the TreeViewItem `Style` which refer to event handlers in your code-behind:

```
<TreeView ... >
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" >
            <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.Expanded" Handler="OnTreeExpanded" />
            <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.Collapsed" Handler="OnTreeCollapsed" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
```

Code-behind - normal event handlers:

```
private void OnTreeExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tvi = (TreeViewItem)sender;
    ...
    e.Handled = true;
}
private void OnTreeCollapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tvi = (TreeViewItem)sender;
    ...
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Note: Make sure you set `e.Handled = true` in the event handlers, or else you'll get events from all parents of the current TreeViewItem as well..