# MVVM wpf TreeView how to handle Expanded event

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, prism, eventtrigger

I'm implementing a delayed load treeview, and need to handle the Expanded event.  I would like to do it directly in the ViewModel.  I have hooked up an EventTrigger:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Expanded">
        <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding HandleExpandCmd}" TriggerParameterPath="OriginalSource"  />
    </i:EventTrigger>  
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

While this works as expected, the OriginalSource is a TreeViewItem, and I would prefer to *not* include System.Windows.Controls in my ViewModel.
Alternatively, I could handle the event in code-behind, and pass the TreeViewItems's DataContext to the ViewModel.  (The DataContext, of course, is what the ViewModel needs to work with.)
Is there a syntax I can use in the TriggerParameterPath that passes the TVI's DataContext, instead of the TVI itself?
Thanks ---

Comment: You can use <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding HandleExpandCmd}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"  />

Comment: @Ayyappan Subramanian -- Thanks, but that gets the ViewModel for the TreeView, not the ViewModel for the item bound to the TVI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to bind the `TreeViewItem`'s `IsExpanded` property to one in your ViewModel. Then you can handle it in the ViewModel however you want!

[Here is an example of how to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15973501/193320)

Comment: Hutter:  Thanks -- that should work.  Bubble up the change in the TVI's VM via OnPropertyChanged, and handle it in the VM for the TreeView.